# Dropping rows with same values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe (df) with a column called "id". I have another dataframe (df2) with only one column called "id". I want to drop the rows in df that have the same values in "id" as df2.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### use boolean indexing with the `isin` method.

Note that the tilde `~` indicates that I take the negation of the boolean series returned by `df['id'].isin(df2['id'])`

```
df[~df['id'].isin(df2['id'])]
```

### `query`

Using a query string we refer `df2` using the `@` symbol.

```
df.query('id not in @df2.id')
```

Comment: Are there any benefits to using the query method?

Comment: I like `query` because it is often clearer as to what my intent was/is.  And for large data sets, `query` is often more performant than other methods.